# How can I properly query this?

Tags: mysql

I am planning on making a comment-reply system inside of a site. (A simple one)

I searched through youtube related to this, and I found a good source. The problem is, he has a 2 separate queries, one for parent comment and two for reply to parent comment and what's more is that the second query is inside a `foreach` loop (bad practice). So, I need to revised of how he query the comments and the tables.

This is the table I came up with:

```
comment_table
id | post_id | comment_id | date | message | reply_id

//In the source, he has 2 tables, parent and child comment table.
```

I want to create a single query where parent comments and child comments are get back at the same time, but I am not sure if it will work.

Let's say I have a table like this.

```
id | post_id | comment_id |     date | message | reply_id
 1 |       2 |          3 | jan 2016 |   hello |
 2 |       2 |          4 | feb 2016 |  hello2 |
 3 |       2 |          5 | mar 2016 |  hello3 |        3
```

**Note:** `reply_id` is where the `comment_id` replied to.

I need to output this results like this:

```
Comments

hello2 //comment
hello //comment
   hello3 //reply
```

This is what I need to do:

- Get all comments in `DESC` order by `date` **while** checking if `reply_id` is not empty, and if not empty, it will check it based on `reply_id` in `DESC` order by `date`.

My problem is, the I only thing that I know how to query is the first part and that is to **Get all comments in `DESC` order by `date`**, the rest is I do not know.

My question is, is this possible to query? If so, what `syntax` do I need here? If you have a better solution than mine, please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

The name `reply_id` is a bit confusing.  Consider `in_reply_to` or `parent_id`.
I assume that `post_id` is the id for the entire thread?  Maybe it should be called `thread_id`?  ("Post", to me, is somewhat synonymous with "post".)

I don't think you need two tables, at least not for comments.  However, if you do have information about the thread as a whole, I recommend a separate table for that; it would have `PRIMARY KEY(thread_id)`.

What's the problem with this?

```
SELECT ...
    FROM ...
    WHERE thread_id = 2
    ORDER BY id DESC;
```

Can have multiple replies to a single comment?  If so, you should change the question to make that clear.  It adds a level of complexity.

You seem to have a "hierarchical" tree.  But, since you have `post_id`, the above query should get all of the messages, approximately in chronological order.

Why have `comment_id` if you already have `id`?

Or, start over...

- Information about the entire `Thread` is in a separate table, and identified by `thread_id`.
- The `Comments` are in a second table, with `PRIMARY KEY(thread_id, comment_id)`. `comment_id` can simply be an `AUTO_INCREMENT`.
- Each comment in a "thread" has the same `thread_id`.
- Each row has a unique `comment_id`.
- "Replies" need to identify their `parent_id`.

Comment: Yes, `post_id` is like `thread_id`. `comment_id` is the parent comment, while `reply_id` is the child comment or simply a reply to the (parent) comment. In your 4th list, `comment_id` might not be necessarily unique because, a user can reply in the same thread infinite times.